# Adjust Color Space of Android Device

Tags: android, android-studio, colors

I haven't tried coding in android studio and I am planning to create an app using this IDE that would require modifications of the color space of the device, like adjusting the intensity of the red, blue, or green, not just the gamma. I am curious if it is possible since there is a *simulate colorspace* feature in developer options located in settings.

Comment: I asked this question in order to find a way to manage the camera preview of the device but I found out that image processing is used to manipulate the color from the camera preview.

Comment: Real-time Image Processing is what I am actually looking for.

Comment: Do you feel as though the latest introduction in Oreo and Pie have provided you with the `ColorSpace` `adaptation` and `connect` features that you desire in order to map your colors on screen to the color spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible. [Android O will be the first version that supports color management.](https://developer.android.com/preview/api-overview.html#cm)

There is a [DisplayTransformManager](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/display/DisplayTransformManager.java?autodive=0%2F%2F) class that's part of Android since Lollipop and is used to implement the *simulate colorspace* feature but, [according to this post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/automate-user/Rs77WpdWAqw/dBk4aVcKHQAJ), modifying settings in the Global or Secure category requires a rooted device.